# Where should User relationship be managed/maintained in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, development, workflow

I have manager and employee reporting to manager. The sharepoint server is integrated with active directory and active directory does not maintain any such relationship.

So how can we do that ?

Can we create user group in sharepoint 2010 and then maintain the relation ? But if so then how to use the relationship in workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically user profiles would hold this information.

You can set SharePoint up to synchronise with Active Directory (as you have done). In the event where a field (manager) is not being brought down from AD then you can use SharePoint to manage it.

This link should help
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721054.aspx

Hope that helps

Comment: can we manage the relationship using custom sharepoint user-groups and then query accordingly.

Comment: Typically SharePoint groups are used to represent roles (usual in terms of what permissions and rights they have) and not relationships. They aren't really designed to capture in such a way that you can store relational data in them.

I would look at user profiles firstly, as the ability to associate a person with a manager is built in.

In fact there is a out-of-the-box control in SharePoint that visualises the organisational hierarchy using the values in this fields.

Comment: Can you please share the name or demo page link of out-of-box control used for visualising organisational hierarchy.

Comment: Please see: http://adminsonnetwork.wordpress.com/2012/06/03/organization-browser-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Thankyou very much. You have really helped a lot.